# Keras 2D input to 2D output

Tags: python, machine-learning, keras, time-series, forecasting

First, I have read [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42154792/keras-custom-layer-2d-input-2d-output) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36293208/keras-2d-input-2d-output) questions with similar names to mine and still do not have an answer.

I want to build a feedforward network for sequence prediction. (I realize that RNNs are more suitable for this task, but I have my reasons). The sequences are of length 128 and each element is a vector with 2 entries, so each batch should be of shape `(batch_size, 128, 2)` and the target is the next step in the sequence, so the target tensor should be of shape `(batch_size, 1, 2)`.

The network architecture is something like this:

```
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(Dense(50, batch_input_shape=(None, 128, 2), kernel_initializer="he_normal" ,activation="relu"))
    model.add(Dense(20, kernel_initializer="he_normal", activation="relu"))
    model.add(Dense(5, kernel_initializer="he_normal", activation="relu"))
    model.add(Dense(2))
```

But trying to train I get the following error:

```
ValueError: Error when checking target: expected dense_4 to have shape (128, 2) but got array with shape (1, 2)
```

I've tried variations like:

```
model.add(Dense(50, input_shape=(128, 2), kernel_initializer="he_normal" ,activation="relu"))
```

but get the same error.

Comment: I don't know the task but there are several ways to arrange feedforward nns with (128,2) as input and (1,2) as output. Maybe you can explain why you think it is a sequence of 128 with 2 vectors at a time instead of a sequence of 2 with 128 vectors at a time?

Comment: Since these are time series with 128 steps (each step a 2-entry vector) each and I'd like to retain the temporal relation

Comment: It seems you are looking for the`TimeDistributed` wrapper, but you anwer confuses me. If there are 128 steps in time and 2 vector at each time, what is the dimensionality of the vectors? and where in you network you want to colaps time dimension into 1 step? are these two enteries compose with eachother? or they need to be kept separately?

Comment: @Mehdi Thank you for mentioning TimeDistributed, I was not familiar with this wrapper. Perhaps my wording was problematic, I meant each sequence is of the shape [[x1_1, x1_2], [x2_1, x1_2], [x2_1, x1_2], ...124 steps..., [x128_1, x128_2]]. and x_1 and x_2 are independent.

Comment: @Mehdi @H.Rappeport Just a side note: as I mentioned in my answer, since [Dense layer is applied on the last axis](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52092176/2099607), there is no difference between `TimeDistributed(Dense(...))` and `Dense(...)`.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

If you take a look at the `model.summary()` output you will see that what the issue is:

```
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense_13 (Dense)             (None, 128, 50)           150       
_________________________________________________________________
dense_14 (Dense)             (None, 128, 20)           1020      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_15 (Dense)             (None, 128, 5)            105       
_________________________________________________________________
dense_16 (Dense)             (None, 128, 2)            12        
=================================================================
Total params: 1,287
Trainable params: 1,287
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

As you can see, the output of the model is `(None, 128,2)` and not `(None, 1, 2)` (or `(None, 2)`) as you expected. So, you may or may not know that [Dense layer is applied on the last axis of its input array](https://stackoverflow.com/a/52092176/2099607) and as a result, as you see above, the time axis and dimension is preserved until the end.

How to resolve this? You mentioned you don't want to use a RNN layer, therefore you have two options: you need to either use `Flatten` layer somewhere in the model or you can also use some Conv1D + Pooling1D layers or even a GlobalPooling layer. For example (these are just for demonstration, you may do it differently):

**using `Flatten` layer**

```
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(Dense(50, batch_input_shape=(None, 128, 2), kernel_initializer="he_normal" ,activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(20, kernel_initializer="he_normal", activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(5, kernel_initializer="he_normal", activation="relu"))
model.add(Flatten())
model.add(Dense(2))

model.summary()
```

Model summary:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense_17 (Dense)             (None, 128, 50)           150       
_________________________________________________________________
dense_18 (Dense)             (None, 128, 20)           1020      
_________________________________________________________________
dense_19 (Dense)             (None, 128, 5)            105       
_________________________________________________________________
flatten_1 (Flatten)          (None, 640)               0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_20 (Dense)             (None, 2)                 1282      
=================================================================
Total params: 2,557
Trainable params: 2,557
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

**using `GlobalAveragePooling1D` layer**

```
model = models.Sequential()
model.add(Dense(50, batch_input_shape=(None, 128, 2), kernel_initializer="he_normal" ,activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(20, kernel_initializer="he_normal", activation="relu"))
model.add(GlobalAveragePooling1D())
model.add(Dense(5, kernel_initializer="he_normal", activation="relu"))
model.add(Dense(2))

model.summary()
```

​Model summary:

```
_________________________________________________________________
Layer (type)                 Output Shape              Param #   
=================================================================
dense_21 (Dense)             (None, 128, 50)           150       
_________________________________________________________________
dense_22 (Dense)             (None, 128, 20)           1020      
_________________________________________________________________
global_average_pooling1d_2 ( (None, 20)                0         
_________________________________________________________________
dense_23 (Dense)             (None, 5)                 105       
_________________________________________________________________
dense_24 (Dense)             (None, 2)                 12        
=================================================================
Total params: 1,287
Trainable params: 1,287
Non-trainable params: 0
_________________________________________________________________
```

Note that in both cases above you need to reshape the labels (i.e. targets) array to `(n_samples, 2)` (or you may want to use a `Reshape` layer at the end).

Comment: Thank you. Followup question (which may or may not deserve asking a separate question): What is the effect of the location of the flatten layer? Would it make any difference if it were placed before the first layer or the last?

Comment: @H.Rappeport Of course it does. It changes the connections. As I mentioned in my answer, `Dense` layer is applied on the last axis and the weights **are shared (i.e. same weights are applied)**. To clarify this take a look at the second Dense layer in the models summaries above. You see that it has 1020 parameters: 50 parameters per each of those units (50 * 20 = 1000) which is connected to the each row (i.e. 50 elements) in the previous layer, plus one bias parameter per unit (20). Now put a Flatten layer before this layer: the number of parameters would be 128*50*20+20. Totally different!